# Error 500, not sure what is causing it

Tags: php, forms

I'm creating a simple MySQL interface through php for a homework assignment.  The user enters their name, password, and sql query, and it spits back a response.  Everything works when I have the user enter the name and password each time, but I'm trying to make it so if a user is already logged in, it displays their username and a logout button instead of giving them the option to login. When I use the basic html form and have the user enter the name and password every time, there are no problems.  When I try to use the php version of the form, I get a 500 error and the page won't load.  Where am I going wrong?

HTML version of the form:

```
        <form action="?" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="username" autofocus="auotfocus" <?php if(isset($_POST['user'])) echo 'value="'.$_POST['user'].'" '; ?> />
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password" <?php if(isset($_POST['pass'])) echo 'value="'.$_POST['pass'].'" '; ?>/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Query" />
            <br />
            <textarea name="sql" rows="10" cols="50" wrap="soft" placeholder="enter an SQL command..."><?php if(isset($_POST['sql'])) echo $_POST['sql']; ?></textarea>
        </form>
```

PHP version of the form (?php brackets omitted:

```
        if(isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
            echo '<form action="?" method="post"'>;
            echo '<h1>Welcome back'.$_SESSION["user"];
            echo '</h1><button type="submit" value="Logout">< br/>';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit Query" /> <br />';
            echo '<textarea name="sql" rows="10" cols="50" wrap="soft" placeholder="enter an SQL command...">'. if(isset($_POST['sql'])) echo $_POST['sql'].'</textarea>';
            echo '</form>';
        }

        else {
            echo '<form action="?" method="post"'>;
            echo '<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="username" />';
            echo '<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password"/>';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit Query" />'.' <br />';
            echo '<textarea name="sql" rows="10" cols="50" wrap="soft" placeholder="enter an SQL command...">'. if(isset($_POST['sql'])) echo $_POST['sql'].'</textarea>';
            echo '</form>';
            }
```

Comment: A 500 error means check your error logs, or enable `display_errors`.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  But it looks like the problem is that `if ($_POST['sql'])` which is illegally concatenated onto the previous string.

Comment: Instead, use a ternary: `'...enter an SQL commend...' . (isset($_POST['sql']) ? $_POST['sql'] : '') . '</textarea>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have an error in your `echo` statement.

```
echo '<form action="?" method="post"'>;
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that part of the echo statement.  Thank you!